# Quick re-install remotely the needed plugins when upgrading Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I moved from Indigo to Luna Eclipse. Indigo and Luna are located in different area, meaning most of the plugins which my tool uses does not exists in the new Eclipse.
So I get errors for places like:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
```

And also in the `plugin.xml` file:

```
<extension
     id="application"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
  <application>
     <run
           class="Application">
     </run>
  </application>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
  <perspective
        name="RCP Perspective"
        class="Perspective"
        id="MyFirstRCP.perspective">
  </perspective>
</extension>
```

So I hope someone can answer the following questions:

1. Is there a quick way to re-download the needed plugins using the Eclipse (without third-party tools)?
2. If not, is it safe to just copy the needed plugins from the old directory to the new one?

The MAINFEST.MF file looks as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: [TOOL_NAME]
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.[TOOL_NAME];singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 3.6.4
Bundle-Activator: com.[TOOL_NAME].core.Activator
Require-Bundle: com.[PATH].util;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].commons;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].commons.testmanagement;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].testlevel.ui;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].report;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.apache.commons.io;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 com.[TOOL_NAME].console;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].scm;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].preferences;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].scm.testio;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.[TOOL_NAME].disk;bundle-version="1.0.0",
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

I replaced the tool name and its path with `[TOOL_NAME]` so it will be more readable. I have problems with `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and `org.eclipse.ui`.

Comment: Again those are core classes which exist in all versions of Eclipse. What are the exact errors you are getting? What is in your plug-in's MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: In the MANIFEST.MF file I have two dependencies with an error: `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and `org.eclipse.ui`. It just says: `Bundle 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' cannot be resolved`.

Comment: Also, you are right. Those plugins do exist in the eclipse. Why Eclipse does not see them?

Comment: I don't know because you still have not shown us the MANIFEST.MF - we need to actually see it to stand a chance of knowing what is wrong

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the reply. I updated the post.

Comment: What version of Java are you using to try and run the RCP?

Comment: I use `Java1.6`. Planning to move to `OpenJDK8` in the future. For now, only switching the versions of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Luna requires a minimum of Java 7 to run, it will not run on Java 6. This applies to RCPs built on this platform as well as Eclipse itself.

Your errors are because the `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` levels for some of the core Eclipse plug-ins are not being meet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When switching to `OpenJDK8`, besides setting the OpenJDK8 path in the `Preferences -> Installed JRE's`, where should I change the version? In the MAINFEST file I have also `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6`. Should I change it also? If yes, to what then?

Comment: What your plug-ins say doesn't need to change. What matters is the Java you use to actually run the RCP. If you are running from inside Eclipse that is the 'Run > Run Configuration' for the RCP. If  you are running outside of Eclipse (from a shortcut or the command line) it depends how Java in your OS is configured or what you specify in the RCP's .ini file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote you in the private chat. Hope you have some time to spare.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't do chat. I just answer questions.